# TEdit not redrawing correctly with Invalidate in Delphi 5

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

There's a problem with the TScrollBox in Delphi 5 when using Cirtix, on some systems, when a user scrolls by clicking the button at the top or bottom of the end of scrollbar the whole application freezes. We had the issue in QucikReports previews initially and got round it by implementing our own scrollbars in the TScrollBox.

We now have a piece of bespoke work that uses a TScrollBox and the client is reporting a similar problem so I'm working round it in the same way. I hide the TScrollBox scrollbars and add in my own. When those are clicked I call the following.

Note, this test code is not currently running in Citrix, I've tested on XP and Window 7.

I am turning off redrawing of the control, moving all the child controls, then turning drawing back on and calling Invalidate. I would expect invalidate to fully redraw the control but that's not happening.

```
procedure TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.ScrollControls(x: Integer; y: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if (x = 0) and (y = 0) then
    Exit;

  // Stop the control from repaining while we're updating it
  try
    SendMessage(FScrollBox.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 0, 0);

    for I := 0 to FScrollBox.ControlCount - 1 do
    begin
      if (FScrollBox.Controls[I] = FVScrollBar) or (FScrollBox.Controls[I] = FHScrollBar) then
        Continue;

      FScrollBox.Controls[I].Left := FScrollBox.Controls[I].Left + x;
      FScrollBox.Controls[I].Top := FScrollBox.Controls[I].Top + y;
    end;

  finally
    // Turn on painting again
    SendMessage(FScrollBox.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 1, 0);
  end;
  // Redraw everything
  InvalidateEverything(FScrollBox);
end;
```

Code to redraw controls

```
procedure TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.InvalidateEverything(AControl: TControl);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  AControl.Invalidate();

  if (AControl is TWinControl) then
    for I := 0 to TWinControl(AControl).ControlCount - 1 do
      InvalidateEverything(TWinControl(AControl).Controls[I]);
end;
```

I added in the Invalidate, Refresh and Reapint and loop through all child controls in an effort to get it working, but still no luck. The edit boxes look as follows:

[image]

If I set Visible to false and back to true then they'll redraw correctly, but there is obviously a horrible flicker. They also redraw correctly if I minimise the maximise the window, or drag it off and on the screen.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**edit : Some info about the answers.**

Users looking for a solution, I'd recommend you try both. David's and Sertac's. David's looks like it is the correct solution according to Microsoft's documentation. However, with the Delphi scrollbox, labels placed directly in the scrollbox flicker, where are labels placed in groupboxes in the scrollbox are perfectly smooth. I think this might be an issue with all components that don't descend from TWinControl. Scrolling itself is smoother with David's solution, but there's less flicking using WM_SETREDRAW and RedrawWindow. I would have liked to accept both as answers as both have their advantages and disadvantages.

**edit : Code for the whole class below**
To test just add a scrollbox with some controls to your form and call

```
TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.Create(ScrollBox1);
```

.

```
unit ScrollBoxScrollReplacement;

interface

uses extctrls, stdctrls, SpScrollBox, forms, Controls, classes, Messages, Windows, Sysutils, Math;

type
  TScrollBoxScrollReplacement = class(TComponent)
  private
    FLastVScrollPos: Integer;
    FLastHScrollPos: Integer;
    FScrollBox: TScrollBox;
    FVScrollBar: TScrollBar;
    FHScrollBar: TScrollBar;
    FVScrollBarVisible: Boolean;
    FHScrollBarVisible: Boolean;
    FCornerPanel: TPanel;
    FMaxRight: Integer;
    FMaxBottom: Integer;
    FOriginalResizeEvent: TNotifyEvent;
    FOriginalCanResizeEvent: TCanResizeEvent;
    FInScroll: Boolean;
    function GetHScrollHeight: Integer;
    function GetVScrollWidth: Integer;
    procedure ReplaceScrollBars;
    function SetUpScrollBar(AControlScrollBar: TControlScrollBar; AKind: TScrollBarKind): TScrollBar;
    procedure ScrollBoxResize(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ScrollBarEnter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PositionScrollBars;
    procedure Scroll(Sender: TObject; ScrollCode: TScrollCode; var ScrollPos: Integer);
    procedure ScrollControls(x, y: Integer);
    procedure CalculateControlExtremes();
    procedure ResetVScrollBarRange;
    procedure ResetHScrollBarRange;
    function IsReplacementControl(AControl: TControl): Boolean;
    property HScrollHeight: Integer read GetHScrollHeight;
    property VScrollWidth: Integer read GetVScrollWidth;
    procedure ScrollBoxCanResize(Sender: TObject; var NewWidth,
      NewHeight: Integer; var Resize: Boolean);
  public
    constructor Create(AScrollBox: TScrollBox); reintroduce; overload;
    destructor Destroy(); override;
    procedure ResetScrollBarRange();
    procedure BringReplacementControlsToFront();
  end;

implementation

{ TScrollBoxScrollReplacement }

constructor TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.Create(AScrollBox: TScrollBox);
begin
  // Set up the scrollbox as our owner so we're destroyed when the scrollbox is
  inherited Create(AScrollBox);

  FScrollBox := AScrollBox;
  ReplaceScrollBars();

  // We make a note of any existing resize and can resize events so we can call them to make sure we don't break anything
  FOriginalResizeEvent := FScrollBox.OnResize;
  FScrollBox.OnResize := ScrollBoxResize;

  FOriginalCanResizeEvent := FScrollBox.OnCanResize;
  FScrollBox.OnCanResize := ScrollBoxCanResize;
end;

// This is called (unintuitively) when controls are moved within the scrollbox. We can use this to reset our scrollbar ranges

procedure TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.ScrollBoxCanResize(Sender: TObject; var NewWidth,
  NewHeight: Integer; var Resize: Boolean);
begin
  if (not FInScroll) then
  begin
    ResetScrollBarRange();
    BringReplacementControlsToFront();
  end;

  if (Assigned(FOriginalCanResizeEvent)) then
    FOriginalCanResizeEvent(Sender, NewWidth, NewHeight, Resize);
end;


procedure TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.ScrollBoxResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (Assigned(FOriginalResizeEvent)) then
    FOriginalResizeEvent(Sender);

  ResetScrollBarRange();
end;

// Hides the original scrollbars and adds in ours

procedure TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.ReplaceScrollBars();
begin
  FVScrollBar := SetUpScrollBar(FScrollBox.VertScrollBar, sbVertical);
  FVScrollBarVisible := FVScrollBar.Visible;
  FHScrollBar := SetUpScrollBar(FScrollBox.HorzScrollBar, sbHorizontal);
  FHScrollBarVisible := FHScrollBar.Visible;

  FCornerPanel := TPanel.Create(FScrollBox);
  FCornerPanel.Parent := FScrollBox;

  ResetScrollBarRange();
end;


procedure TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.PositionScrollBars();
begin
  // Align our scrollbars correctly
  FVScrollBar.Top := 0;
  FVScrollBar.Left := FScrollBox.ClientWidth - FVScrollBar.Width;
  FVScrollBar.Height := FScrollBox.ClientHeight - HScrollHeight;
  //  FVScrollBar.BringToFront();

  FHScrollBar.Left := 0;
  FHScrollBar.Top := FScrollBox.ClientHeight - FHScrollBar.Height;
  FHScrollBar.Width := FScrollBox.ClientWidth - VScrollWidth;
  //  FHScrollBar.BringToFront();

    // If both scrollbars are visible we'll put a panel in the corner so we can't see components through it
  if (FVScrollBar.Visible) and (FHScrollBar.Visible) then
  begin
    FCornerPanel.Left := FHScrollBar.Width;
    FCornerPanel.Top := FVScrollBar.Height;
    FCornerPanel.Width := FVScrollBar.Width;
    FCornerPanel.Height := FHScrollBar.Height;
    FCornerPanel.Visible := True;
    //    FCornerPanel.BringToFront();
  end
  else
    FCornerPanel.Visible := False;
end;


procedure TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.ResetScrollBarRange();
begin
  CalculateControlExtremes();

  ResetVScrollBarRange();
  ResetHScrollBarRange();

  PositionScrollBars();
end;

procedure TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.ResetVScrollBarRange();
var
  ScrollMax: Integer;
  ScrollAmount: Integer;
begin
  // If all the controls fit to the right of the screen, but there are controls off the left then we'll scroll right.
  ScrollMax := FMaxBottom - FScrollBox.ClientHeight + FHScrollBar.Height;
  if (ScrollMax < 0) and (FLastVScrollPos > 0) then
  begin
    ScrollAmount := Min(Abs(ScrollMax), FLastVScrollPos);
    ScrollControls(0, ScrollAmount);
    FLastVScrollPos := FLastVScrollPos - ScrollAmount;
    CalculateControlExtremes();
  end;

  FVScrollBar.Max := Max(FMaxBottom - FScrollBox.ClientHeight + FHScrollBar.Height + FLastVScrollPos, 0);
  FVScrollBar.Visible := (FVScrollBar.Max > 0) and FVScrollBarVisible;
end;


procedure TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.ResetHScrollBarRange();
var
  ScrollMax: Integer;
  ScrollAmount: Integer;
begin
  // If all the controls fit to the bottom of the screen, but there are controls off the top then we'll scroll up.
  ScrollMax := FMaxRight - FScrollBox.ClientWidth + FVScrollBar.Width;
  if (ScrollMax < 0) and (FLastHScrollPos > 0) then
  begin
    ScrollAmount := Min(Abs(ScrollMax), FLastHScrollPos);
    ScrollControls(ScrollAmount, 0);
    FLastHScrollPos := FLastHScrollPos - ScrollAmount;
    CalculateControlExtremes();
  end;

  FHScrollBar.Max := Max(FMaxRight - FScrollBox.ClientWidth + FVScrollBar.Width + FLastHScrollPos, 0);
  FHScrollBar.Visible := (FHScrollBar.Max > 0) and FHScrollBarVisible;
end;


function TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.SetUpScrollBar(AControlScrollBar: TControlScrollBar; AKind: TScrollBarKind): TScrollBar;
begin
  Result := TScrollBar.Create(FScrollBox);
  Result.Visible := AControlScrollBar.Visible;
  Result.Parent := FScrollBox;
  Result.Kind := AKind;
  Result.Ctl3D := False;
  Result.Max := AControlScrollBar.Range;
  Result.OnEnter := ScrollBarEnter;
  Result.OnScroll := Scroll;
  Result.SmallChange := 5;
  Result.LargeChange := 20;

  AControlScrollBar.Visible := False;
end;

destructor TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;

procedure TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.ScrollBarEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // We just call this here to make sure our ranges are set correctly - a backup in case things go wrong
  ResetScrollBarRange();
end;

procedure TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.Scroll(Sender: TObject;
  ScrollCode: TScrollCode; var ScrollPos: Integer);
var
  Change: Integer;
begin
  ResetScrollBarRange();

  if (Sender = FVScrollBar) then
  begin
    Change := FLastVScrollPos - ScrollPos;
    ScrollControls(0, Change);
    FLastVScrollPos := ScrollPos;
  end
  else if (Sender = FHScrollBar) then
  begin
    Change := FLastHScrollPos - ScrollPos;
    ScrollControls(Change, 0);
    FLastHScrollPos := ScrollPos;
  end;
end;

// Moves all the controls in the scrollbox except for the scrollbars we've added

{procedure TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.ScrollControls(x: Integer; y: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if (x = 0) and (y = 0) then
    Exit;

  // Stop the control from repaining while we're updating it
  SendMessage(FScrollBox.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 0, 0);
  FInScroll := True;
  try
    for I := 0 to FScrollBox.ControlCount - 1 do
    begin
      if IsReplacementControl(FScrollBox.Controls[I]) then
        Continue;

      FScrollBox.Controls[I].Left := FScrollBox.Controls[I].Left + x;
      FScrollBox.Controls[I].Top := FScrollBox.Controls[I].Top + y;
    end;

  finally
    // Turn on painting again
    FInScroll := False;
    SendMessage(FScrollBox.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 1, 0);
  end;

  // Redraw everything
  RedrawWindow(FSCrollBox.Handle, nil, 0, RDW_ERASE or RDW_INVALIDATE or RDW_ALLCHILDREN);
end;  }


procedure TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.ScrollControls(x: Integer; y: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
  Control: TControl;
  WinControl: TWinControl;
  hWinPosInfo: HDWP;
begin
  if (x = 0) and (y = 0) then
    Exit;

  hWinPosInfo := BeginDeferWindowPos(0);
  Win32Check(hWinPosInfo<>0);
  try
    for I := 0 to FScrollBox.ControlCount - 1 do
    begin
      Control := FScrollBox.Controls[I];
      if (Control = FVScrollBar) or (Control = FHScrollBar) then
        Continue;
      if Control is TWinControl then
      begin
        WinControl := FScrollBox.Controls[I] as TWinControl;
        hWinPosInfo := DeferWindowPos(
          hWinPosInfo,
          WinControl.Handle,
          0,
          WinControl.Left + x,
          WinControl.Top + y,
          WinControl.Width,
          WinControl.Height,
          SWP_NOZORDER or SWP_NOOWNERZORDER or SWP_NOACTIVATE
        );
        Win32Check(hWinPosInfo<>0);
      end
      else
        Control.SetBounds(Control.Left + x, Control.Top + y, Control.Width, Control.Height);
    end;
  finally
    EndDeferWindowPos(hWinPosInfo);
  end;
end;



// works out where our right most and bottom most controls are so we can set the scrollbars correctly

procedure TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.CalculateControlExtremes();
var
  I: Integer;
  Right: Integer;
  Bottom: Integer;
begin
  FMaxRight := 0;
  FMaxBottom := 0;
  for I := 0 to FScrollBox.ControlCount - 1 do
  begin
    if IsReplacementControl(FScrollBox.Controls[I]) then
      Continue;

    Right := FScrollBox.Controls[I].Left + FScrollBox.Controls[I].Width;
    Bottom := FScrollBox.Controls[I].Top + FScrollBox.Controls[I].Height;

    FMaxRight := Max(FMaxRight, Right);
    FMaxBottom := Max(FMaxBottom, Bottom);
  end;
end;

function TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.GetHScrollHeight: Integer;
begin
  if (FHScrollBar.Visible) then
    Result := FHScrollBar.Height
  else
    Result := 0;
end;

function TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.GetVScrollWidth: Integer;
begin
  if (FVScrollBar.Visible) then
    Result := FVScrollBar.Width
  else
    Result := 0;
end;

// Returns true if the passed control is one of the controls we've added

function TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.IsReplacementControl(
  AControl: TControl): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (AControl = FVScrollBar) or (AControl = FHScrollBar) or (AControl = FCornerPanel);
end;

procedure TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.BringReplacementControlsToFront;
begin
  FVScrollBar.BringToFront();
  FHScrollBar.BringToFront();
  FCornerPanel.BringToFront();
end;

end.
```

Comment: Randomly calling all of Invalidate, Repaint and Refresh is rather pointless. The latter two are the same, and both call Invalidate. Presumably the original code called just Invalidate. It seems pointless that you iterate over the children since that happens automatically. And the cast to TWinControl is rather worrying. Please don't cast things to what they are not.

Comment: Yes, this is code I've been hacking around with. I would have assumed a simple call to Invalidate on the ScrollBox would have worked - but it didn't. I left that code there as it shows what I've tried. As you can see from the screen shot - this is a test app, it's a long way from release.

Comment: Essentially you just need `FScrollBox.Invalidate` and can scrap `InvalidateEverything`. Do you really have that function in your production code? With the for loop and the bogus cast? Surely that causes problems.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan As said, this is test code. I was just calling FScrollBox.Invalidate. That didn't work. As you can see from the Screenshot, everything there is a TWinControl. Just calling FScrollBox.Invalidate wouldn't redraw the panels correctly. Looping though the children fixes that, but the editboxes are not drawing correctly. This is not release code - this is code to try and solve a problem that I'll tidy up later. If you can help solve the problem that would be appreciated.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Refresh calls Repaint, but they don't call Invalidate.  Repaint paint immediately, while Invalidate works through a message, and is thus processed only when the appliction becomes idle, or Application.ProcessMessages is called. For a case like this, Invalide should be the only thing necessary, it is the best solution if you want to repaint something in response to a user action like clicking or scrolling. Also, this repainting propagates to the parents, so you don't have to call this recursively for every parent/child in your tree of controls.

Comment: @GolezTrol In my VCL, `Repaint` is implemented as `Invalidate; Update;`. What version of the VCL are you looking at. Invalidate calls `InvalidateRect` and then when the message queue is next emptied a `WM_PAINT` message is synthesized.

Comment: It seems you are right. I was a bit confused, looking at TControl.Repaint and .Invalidate. But in TWinControl it works exactly as you describe, and even in TControl it is similar.

Comment: @GolezTrol This test code is running in Windows XP - no Citrix involved here (yet).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've added the complete class so you can test your theories yourself if you wish.

Comment: @Will Do you understand my point about the cast?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes - like I said, this is test code. The cast is not a problem for this test. The problem is the redrawing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that your code started working once I remove the two `WM_SETREDRAW` messages. That's your fundamental problem. You will need to remove the `WM_SETREDRAW` messages.

That will no doubt mean you still need to solve your problem with flickering, but that's a different problem. My quick experiments suggest that `DeferWindowPos` could solve that problem. For example:

```
procedure TScrollBoxScrollReplacement.ScrollControls(x: Integer; y: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
  Control: TControl;
  WinControl: TWinControl;
  hWinPosInfo: HDWP;
begin
  if (x = 0) and (y = 0) then
    Exit;

  hWinPosInfo := BeginDeferWindowPos(0);
  Win32Check(hWinPosInfo<>0);
  try
    for I := 0 to FScrollBox.ControlCount - 1 do
    begin
      Control := FScrollBox.Controls[I];
      if (Control = FVScrollBar) or (Control = FHScrollBar) then
        Continue;
      if Control is TWinControl then
      begin
        WinControl := FScrollBox.Controls[I] as TWinControl;
        hWinPosInfo := DeferWindowPos(
          hWinPosInfo,
          WinControl.Handle,
          0,
          WinControl.Left + x,
          WinControl.Top + y,
          WinControl.Width,
          WinControl.Height,
          SWP_NOZORDER or SWP_NOOWNERZORDER or SWP_NOACTIVATE
        );
        Win32Check(hWinPosInfo<>0);
      end
      else
        Control.SetBounds(Control.Left + x, Control.Top + y, Control.Width, Control.Height);
    end;
  finally
    EndDeferWindowPos(hWinPosInfo);
  end;
end;
```

Your non-windowed controls will still flicker, but you can make them windowed, or indeed put the whole content of the scroll box inside a windowed control. Heck, if you just did that, it would be enough to solve the problem!

For what it is worth, my trials indicate that `DeferWindowPos` gives smoother scrolling than `WM_SETREDRAW` and `RedrawWindow`. But these tests were hardly exhaustive and you might find different outcomes in your app.

---

Some asides regarding your code:

Your use of `try/finally` is incorrect. The pattern must be:

```
BeginSomething;
try
  Foo;
finally
  EndSomething;
end;
```

You get that wrong with your calls to `SendMessage`.

And you use an incorrect cast in `InvalidateEverything`. You cannot blindly cast a `TControl` to `TWinControl`. That said, that function does no good. You can remove it altogether. What it is attempting to do can be performed with a single call to `Invalidate` of the parent control.

Comment: I'm well aware of that, the problem is then it also starts flickering - try dragging the scrollbar.

Comment: That might be so, but I'm afraid that this is the answer to the question that you asked. This is why your controls are not re-drawing. If you want to solve the flickering, that's a different question.

Comment: The question I asked is why Invalidate isn't redrawing the controls correctly - Invalidate isn't required if you remove those two lines.

Comment: So, you refuse to contemplate removing `WM_SETREDRAW`?

Comment: If there's another way to stop the flickering then I'll remove them - but I'm not aware of another way. I added them in for that reason.

Comment: Well, that is your way forward. Remove them, and fix the flickering. No flickering here. How can I see flickering.

Comment: Are you dragging the scrollbar rather than clicking the buttons? The main reason I'm concerned about flickering and needless redraws is that it'll be operating over Citrix and all of those redraws will be sent across the Internet. That's why I'd like to eliminate the issue.

Comment: However I operate the scroll bar I cannot see a flicker. Perhaps what you need is `BeginDeferWindowPos` and friends.

Comment: Do you have any panels in your scrollbox? Try adding a panel, or maybe some panels in panels with other child controls. Flickering is most obvious for me on panels.

Comment: Just tested on my Windows 7 host machine rather than my VM - the flickering is indeed less obvious. I can see how someone looking at this could easily think it's a non-issue. It will however be a lot worse on Citrix.

Comment: I can see flickering. I'm certainly not saying flickering is a non-issue. I'm just telling you that removing flickering by breaking the functionality altogether is not the right solution.

Comment: The thing I really don't understand is why Invalidate isn't redrawing the controls correctly. When you minimise and maximise the window, or drag it off and back onto the screen, what is it doing that Invalidate doesn't? If that question could be answered then I suspect the solution would become obvious.

Comment: @WillCalderwood Slow UI is a common problem inside a VM. I have had list boxes scroll slowly the first time they are scrolled amongst other issues. These are also related to the windows UI performance settings. While I am not sure, I wouldn't imagine that these are enabled on a typical Citrix session where performance is preferred.

Comment: @WillCalderwood If the user is in a remote session surely you are not doing live tracking of the scroll box?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If I can get it working well then I will

Comment: I've done a little experiment with `BeginDefWindowPos` and it is much cleaner. But I would also say that a vanilla scroll box is flicker free. Are you sure that you overall approach is the best solution to the root problem.

Comment: I didn't do the original research into the problem, but I know a lot of time (days) was spent on it and the root cause wasn't found, and therefore couldn't be fixed. This is the solution I was asked to implement which is why I'm going down this route. I appreciate the time you're spending on this.

Comment: @WillCalderwood Just a link to an old article on designing for remote desktop http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/01/03/508694.aspx

Comment: Well, I've put a lot of time into this too now. And I've given you multiple solutions. I hope you appreciate it. Simple quick and dirty fix is to stuff everything into a single panel!

Comment: @Graymatter That blog makes an interesting point about the double buffering.

Comment: @WillCalderwood I hope you aren't double buffering or doing smooth scrolling for remote sessions!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I can't say double buffering is something I've ever even thought about with remote sessions - have you? I'm not sure whether Citrix tries to handle this in an elegant way or not. I didn't write the bulk of this code base, and it wasn't written originally with remote sessions as the target, but it's something I will look into.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Looks like double buffering of Delphi forms is off by default so it's not a concern.

Comment: I certainly have handled this issue before. My app does no off screen rendering, aka double buffering, when running in a remote session. I've posted on the topic many times here. Citrix cannot handle this issue. Had to be done by the dev.

Comment: I must say that I was somewhat taken aback by your "I am well aware of that" comment. If you knew that, why didn't you say so? And I would stress that you are mis-using WM_SETREDRAW. It seems that you've made your mind up to use it come what may. I think that is a mistake.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I apologise for the "I am well aware of that" comment. It was abrupt. I was frustrated with the problem and I thought it would have been clear I was trying to prevent the redraw for a reason. As you say, I should have specified that I wanted to prevent needless redraws in the original question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I will also try your DeferWindowPos solution sometime today and will do a comparison. Unfortunately I don't have access to the client Citrix setup to test on that, as that's what I'd want to do.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Having read through the docs it looks like your solution is the correct one. Interestingly, with DeferWindowPos controls draws directly onto the scrollbox flicker terribly - but controls in groupboxes on the scrollbox don't flicker at all. Scrolling is generally smoother however.

Comment: @WillCalderwood I don't see flicker at all for windowed controls. Non-windowed controls will flicker because you cannot use them with `DeferWindowPos`. So, I'm thinking of `TLabel`. Two ways to deal with that: put the non-windowed control inside a windowed container. May not always help. Or replace with a windowed control. Use `TStaticText` rather than `TLabel`. I tend to do the latter.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for that. TStaticText works beautifully. I never knew it even existed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Interestingly, components in panels do flicker, components in groupboxes don't. I don't really have time to look into this now though - what I've got is good enough. Thanks for all your help on this.

Comment: @WillCalderwood Yes, it's one of the biggest tools available for the anti-flicker developer. Non-windowed controls are a headache for flicker.

Answer (score 5):

You can replace your

```
FScrollBox.Invalidate();
```

with

```
RedrawWindow(FSCrollBox.Handle, nil, 0,
    RDW_ERASE or RDW_INVALIDATE or RDW_ALLCHILDREN);
```

to have all controls invalidated and updated properly. `RDW_ERASE` is for erasing the previous positions of controls and `RDW_ALLCHILDREN` is for taking care of windowed controls inside. Non-win controls like labels should already be repainted because of `RDW_INVALIDATE`.

Although this approach may help avoiding the flicker that you observe, it may also cause some loss of smoothness of scrolling while thumb tracking. That's because the scroll position might need to be updated more often than a paint cycle is processed. To circumvent this, instead of invalidating you can update the control positions immediately:

```
RedrawWindow(FSCrollBox.Handle, nil, 0,
    RDW_ERASE or RDW_INVALIDATE or RDW_UPDATENOW or RDW_ALLCHILDREN);
```

Comment: Perfect - exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Time for me to go and read all about RedrawWindow.

Comment: @Sertac Is this better than DeferWindowPos? It seems to me that `WM_SETREDRAW` performs quite a lot worse in terms of smooth scrolling. I know that the asker's mind appears to be set that `WM_SETREDRAW` is the only solution, but I've never really been convinced by its utility.

Comment: @David - I can't really tell. I neither have tried DeferWindowPs nor have seen the box performing in a remote session.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I'm not talking about the remote session. I'm talking about a local session.

Comment: @David - Tried to compare with DeferWindowPos now, I don't notice any difference, some controls display an occasional slight flicker in both methods.

Comment: @Sertac I placed quite a lot of controls in the scroll box to get some discernible flicker.

Comment: @David - In terms of smoothness of course you're right, it's WM_SETREDRAW itself that cause it to become non-smooth. In the end which one is better depends on how each helps the issue we don't observe (flicker). If they'd act similar, not using WM_SETREDRAW is better for thumb tracking.

Comment: @Sertac I also feel quite strongly that semantically DeferWindowPos is the correct solution. WM_SETREDRAW is not designed for mass control movement.

Comment: Users looking for a solution, I'd recommend you try both. David's and Sertac's. David's looks like it is the 'correct' solution according to Microsoft's documentation. However, with the Delphi scrollbox, labels placed directly in the scrollbox flicker, where are labels placed in groupboxes in the scrollbox are perfectly smooth. Scrolling itself is smoother with David's solution, but there's less flicking using WM_SETREDRAW.

Comment: Following on from that, `TLabel` is non-windowed and so `DeferWindowPos` cannot help. Using a windowed control `TStaticText` is one good way to escape that problem.

Comment: @Will - I think I've addressed the *smoothness* issue.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I tried this - it certainly improves the smoothness, but it's still not as smooth as the other approach. The advantage with your approach is that Labels and other controls that don't descent from TWinControl don't flicker.